# Sql query with complex joins

Tags: c#, sql, join, oledb

I am developing c# application.
I am using OLEDB connections.

I have following two tables>>

payment

```
AdmissionNumber  | StudName |

       1            John
       2            Smith
```

paymentDetails

```
   AdmissionNumber  | RemainingFee |    Date         | Payment

        1                5000         10/10/2012         3000
        1                3000         10/11/2012         2000
        2                4000         15/11/2012         3000
        1                1000         10/12/2012         2000
```

In this I want to get the table result as following>>

```
 AdmissionNumber | Name | Date           |RemainingPayment|Payment|
       1           John    10/12/2012          1000         2000
```

In this case Admission number and date is already provided in the form via textbox and datetimepicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this case Admission number and date is already provided in the form
>   via textbox and datetimepicker.

So you want to search for a specific Admission number and a date. If so, then try this:

```
SELECT 
  p.AdmissionNumber,  
  p.Name,   
  pd.Date,
  pd.RemaingFee AS RemainingPayment,
  pd.Payment
FROM Payment p
INNER JOIN PaymentDetails pd ON p.AdmissionNumber = pd.AdmissionNumber
WHERE p.AdmissionNumber = @AdmissionNumberParamFromTxtBox
  AND pd.Date           = @DateParamFromTheotherTextBox;
```

Comment: Its giving me error that no value was given to more than one required parameter

Comment: @freelancer - You have to pass two parameters to the query I posted . It seems like you only pass one parameter. Check your code again.

Comment: thank you I got the idea with this answer and done it sucessfuly. Really thank you.

Comment: problem was because in payment table admissionnumber field was number and in paymentDetails table it was text.I solved it. thanx a lot

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the exact result. Matching between master and the last record of the details. You should have an Primary key column in the details.

```
Select  *
    From    Payment
    Left    Outer   Join
        PaymentDetail
    On  PaymentDetail.Id        =   (
        Select  Top 1
            A.Id
            From    PaymentDetail   As  A
            Where   A.AdmissionNumber   =   Payment.AdmissionNumber
            Order   By  A.Date  Desc
    )
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  p.AdmissionNumber,  
  p.Name,
  MAX(pd.Date) AS Date,
  pd.RemaingFee AS RemainingPayment,
  pd.Payment
FROM Payment p
INNER JOIN PaymentDetails pd ON p.AdmissionNumber = pd.AdmissionNumber
GROUP BY p.AdmissionNumber,pd.Payment,p.Name,pd.RemaingFee
```